# Table belong to which section in word using openxml

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have searched a lot on the internet and I could not find an answer to this. Is there a way to check where does the table belong. That is, which section does the table belong to.

I would prefer to do it using OpenXml, but if there is a solution using Interop Word object. I would take that too...

As a sample document.

[image: screenshot of the word document]

I would have posted the xml for the document as well, but post's limit is reached. To clarify, the example document contains two sections. First one contains two tables and the second contains one table.

Comment: What do you mean by "which section" - what information do you want? The index value? The page orientation? Something else?

Comment: @CindyMeister I want to check where does the table belong to ? I mean, in which section? You can insert section breaks to create multiple chapters in a document which are also called sections.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that. But exatly what information do you want?

Comment: I want to see if the width of the table is greater than the page size or not, which could be different in each section/chapter, so I want to know where is this table currently placed in the document (i.e., in which section/chapter)

Answer (score 0):

Working with the Open XML SDK is very similar to using an XML parser to locate nodes relative to the current node. You're probably familiar with using `Descendants` as that's used in many examples. You can also use `Ancestors` and various `Sibling` criteria for locating a specific node.

In this case, if you inspect the underlying WordOpenXML, you'll see that `<w:tbl>` is  a sibling of `<w:p>`, and `<w:sectPr>` is a child of `<w:p>`. So you want a `NextSibling<Paragraph>` that has a child of type `SectionProperties`.

This is the case for all sections *except* the last (default section for the document). The last `sectPr` is a child of `<w:body>` (sibling of `<w:p>`) and will be the last element before the closing `</w:body>` tag.

Comment: I have two questions. 1) Will that always be the same order? that is, the table and paragraphs will always be in the same order in the xml? 2) Can you share a piece of code to get previous siblings ?

Comment: @NaveedButt I've corrected my Answer (the section break does not precede, it follows - don't know what I was seeing a week ago) and added information about the last section, which doesn't follow the pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cindy, if you could share some reference code that could work as a starting point. It would be great.